# Does anyone know how to code for getting a frame using your webcam?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to get a frame from my webcam but I don't know where the frame is located.

this is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

while True:
  _, frame = cap.read()
  if frame is None:
    break
  cv2.imshow('app', frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you put `opencv save image` into a search engine?

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you posted, the frame is the image that is captured from the webcam at that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
  _, frame = cap.read()
  if frame is None:
    break
  cv2.imshow('app', frame)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

cv2.waitKey(0)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In your program indentation problem in if condition

If you press "q" then the frame is captured, and the frame stored in "frame" variable